# App2 results not recieved on App1

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult, android-data-usage

I am trying to return results to app1 from app2 but `onActivityResults`not getting hit. I have tried both 'startActivityForResult' and new call back methods. Below are my codes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                    "com.example.myapplication1",
                    "com.example.myapplication1.MainActivity"
            ));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
```

My Call back

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        results.setText(data.getStringExtra("TextValue"));
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is how I am returning data to app1 by setting results.

```
Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra("TextValue", ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.valueEntered)).getText().toString());
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

Please guide what is wrong here. What other parts I need to check like intent-filters or activity defination in manifest.

I have tried this [Open app with multiple inner Intents and wait for result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54670070/open-app-with-multiple-inner-intents-and-wait-for-result) but this needs to know activity details before hand. I want this to be generic.